# Animated GIFs vs. jQuery animations performance

Tags: jquery, html

I am building a site which has a bunch of [orbit] carousels (on a single page), and each carousel will have a play/pause button.  The designer wants the pause button on the carousels to pulsate (i.e. change the opacity from 80% to 100% and back down to 80% and have that keep looping).

I was thinking that animated gifs would be less of a performance hit than using jquery, as we have 10+ carousels on the page (don't ask why).  I want to know if I am right.

The jquery code I would use would be something like this (I have not coded it, so don't mind the syntax errors):

```
    function pb_animate () {
        $('.pausebutton').animate({opacity:0.8}, 300[ms], function () {
            $('.pausebutton').animate({opacity:1.0}, 300[ms], function () {
                pb_animate ()
            }
        }
    }
```

So what would be better in this case: jquery or animated gifs?  Or am I worrying about nothing? If you have a better jquery solution/approach, please post it.

Comment: I'd also go with CSS, see @nietonfir's answer.

Answer (score 3):

**CSS3** is the way to go for animations on the web. The following example toggles the opacity between 1 and 0.8 (removed `-{webkit,moz,o}-`prefixes for readability):

```
@keyframes pulse {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    50% {
        opacity: 0.8;
    }
}

.pausebutton {
    animation: pulse 4s infinite;
}
```

Or see this [jsBin](http://jsbin.com/egEYayo/2). (Yep, the pause/play buttons can be done in CSS as well.)

Comment: @matewka Not only does it answer it, but also shows the fastest and the least performance-killing solution for web animations: CSS3!

Comment: That is true. I just didn't notice any description of this solution. There's even no information that this is CSS. How the OP should now that?

Comment: @matewka I see your point. Though, strictly personally speaking, I'd see an answer like this more like a research/knowledge expand opportunity, especially since two comments say it's a great solution. Again, not everyone is like that, and I agree a lot of people like everything served on a plate.

Comment: @richardaday True, but the good thing is that it fails gracefully, just by not showing the pulse effect... I'd be more worried about having 10+ carousels on IE9 :)

Comment: @Shomz, I don't approve spoiling people with answers served on a plate. But on the other side, I always recall the times when I was learning the very basics. Every bit of code was so mysterious that one understatement in a tutorial etc. could ruin my attempts.

Comment: @matewka Updated the answer back to the original and added an example. That was a copy-N-paste issue on my part. I was in a hurry and the pasted CSS overwrote my introductory sentences.

Answer (score 0):

my answer is, it depends, lots of carousels if containing lots of images would cause too much requests to the server which will cause a massive reduction in the page loading time, of course I am not counting the image sizes, if it's text, this could be a little less, the jquery code you use is good, another suggestion is @nietonfir's css3 code, but the result is the same when it comes to server requests, I suggest you read this: [Group Multiple Images into One Request and Response](http://www.cdnconnect.com/demos/grouped-image-requests) for it will drastically increase the speed if using lots of images, I hope this answered your question.